# How can I iterate over cookies using jquery (or just javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using the ["Cookie Plugin" by Klaus Hartl](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) to add or update cookies at `$(document).ready`. I have another event that is supposed to iterate all the cookies and do something with the value of each cookie. How can I iterate over the collection of cookies and get the id and value of each?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
$.cookie.each(function(id, value) { 
            alert('ID='+id+' VAL='+value); 
        });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you just want to look at the cookies it's not that hard without an extra plugin:

```
$.each(document.cookie.split(/; */), function()  {
  var splitCookie = this.split('=');
  // name is splitCookie[0], value is splitCookie[1]
});
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Split with regex is much better.

Comment: All correct except the function definition in the first line. Change function(cookieString) to function(index, cookieString) and you've got it!

Comment: oh right - sorry!  Also I think jQuery binds "this" to each element, so you could also leave it off and just split "this" inside the function.

Comment: actually, you *should* split `this` rather than `cookieString`, for the value of `cookieString` will be the zero-based index of the iteration.

Answer (score 6):

well it's rather easy in plain javascript:

```
var keyValuePairs = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
    var name = keyValuePairs[i].substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('='));
    var value = keyValuePairs[i].substring(keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('=')+1);
}
```

Comment: watch out for the leading spaces! You should split with the regex /; */ instead of just the string ';'.

Comment: I like this solution because it allows equals signs in the cookie values.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution does create white spaces before the name, which gives hard to debug errors.

```
var keyValuePairs = document.cookie.split(/; */);
for(var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
    var name = keyValuePairs[i].substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('='));
    var value = keyValuePairs[i].substring(keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('=')+1);
    ...
```